# Edit Lion default web site pages

Tags: macos, osx-server, webserver

The first part of the question is: where are the actual files that are displayed by apache for the default web server in Lion Server?

Specifically as simple task I would like to change the title of the default web page.
When the address is bookmarked it shows as "OS X Lion Server" and I want to change that.

I looked everywhere and I couldn't find the actual files. Obviously I don't know where to look :-)

Comment: Are you talking about `./Library/WebServer/`? Or perhaps `~/Sites/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default document root for Lion Server is /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/*domainname*.

[Lion Server Advanced Administration](http://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.7) is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had any personal experience with Lion Server, but on the normal Lion, there are two folder locations used for web sharing. The first is hosted by the user, and is found at `~/Sites/`. The second and more likely possibility is the one hosted by the system, found at `./Library/WebServer`. (Note that the first is "`~/`", meaning it's within the user's directory, and the second is "`./`", meaning it's in the system's Library folder.)